# ver el nivel de zoom en leaflet (plugin mapas)

Tags: leaflet

Hola buenas noche (como sino)
Soy algo nuevo en el plugin Leaflet y no he podido encontrar la manera de ver el zoom en el que me encuentro, no el boton zoom, sino el nivel (11, 12, 13, 14 ...etc)
Me podrian ayudar con eso?
Gracias

Answer (score 0):

En leaflet tienes definido un mapa así `const map = L.map("map", options);`.
Entonces con solo llamar
`const currentZoom = map.getZoom();` deberías tener lo que buscas